# Enforcing and using static variables in sub-classes with Java

Tags: java, design-patterns

I would like to use a static variable from a sub-class in a super-class static method. It seems that I'm not able to ensure that variable is present, since it is static and I cannot enforce static members in this way.

Utimately, I'd like to do similar in functionality to this:

```
protected class Page {
    static WebDriver driver = new ChromeWebDriver();
    public static boolean onPage () {
        return driver.findElements(By.id(PAGE_NAME)) != null;
    }
}

public class HomePage extends Page {
    static String PAGE_NAME = "home";
}

public class LoginPage extends Page {
    static String PAGE_NAME = "login";
}

...
HomePage.onPage();
...
```

What is the best pattern for something like this?

Note: The primary requirements are:

- onPage() remain static and
- onPage() takes no parameters

Comment: The question you should ask yourself: why do you want to do that? In other words: why is this better than a non-static abstract method that returns the page name? And in your example, how would calling `Page.onPage()` tell you which page you're on?

Comment: This is not a thing you can possibly do in Java.

Comment: Note: you can't access `driver` like this anyway.

Comment: @Andy Sorry, i fixed that.

Comment: @biziclop I see. Is there another approach that may be preferred to enforce having an onpage function for every page, with a generic implementation? I looked into default interface methods and abstract methods, but they don't work in the case of static methods, as that wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @KyleShrader just don't use static at all. Static and inheritance are anethema.

Comment: @AndyTurner Well, the pages themselves don't have state.

But actually that just makes me think, why am I asking the page if we are on it? It's static - I should be doing as biziclops hinted at and telling something else what page I expect to be on.

Comment: Not having state does not imply use of static. (And nor does use of static imply lack of state).

Comment: @AndyTurner Oh. I could use a Singleton pattern - but I really want to treat the pages as a model of the web-page and not as a object that I'm manipulating. Edit: maybe i have a contorted misunderstanding of the definition of a static object.

Comment: @KyleShrader nor does it imply Singleton. If you have a class with no state (and no side effect in its creation), why does it matter if there is more than one instance of it?

Comment: Well, I don't have any reason to make the objects if i'm not going to treat them as objects.

Comment: @KyleShrader other than you do need to treat them as objects if you want to use inheritance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109963/discussion-between-kyle-shrader-and-andy-turner).

Answer (score 1):

you cannot do that as is. However you have have a final field in the base class and force every drived class provided a parameter to super constructor as in below

```
public abstract class Page {

    final String pageName;

    public Page(String title) {
        pageName = title;
    }
   //the rest implementation
}
```

then you can have your pages like

```
public class HomePage extends Page
 {

    public HomePage()
      {
       super("home");
      } 
  }
```

Another alternative will be to provide abstract getPageName in the base page and implement it in drived classes

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to this point committed to Pages being static. :(

Comment: @KyleShrader that doesn't make the impossible possible.

Comment: @KyleShrader Good luck with it then.